# How do I vertically center a div which has content inside

Tags: html, css

I have two divs div-a and div-b wrapped by another div div-a-b-wrapper.
div-a-b-wrapper is repeatable, so all div-a-b-wrapper are wrapped with another parent div, div-c.

I want to vertically center all div-a-b-wrappers inside div-c. This is the layout I want to achieve:

[image]

This is my HTML,

```
<div class="div-c">
     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">b</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">b</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">b</div>
     </div>

    </div>
```

And this is the CSS I have for it so far,

```
.div-c {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #333;
}

.div-a-b-wrapper {
 width: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 height: 100%;
}

.div-a {
 background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
}

.div-b {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 100%;
}
```

But with this the .div-a-b-wrapper is aligned to the top of div-c.

How do I center .div-a-b-wrapper in div-c?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6kfzLtx3/1/

Comment: Just a point, if your wrappers are repeatable, you really shouldn't be putting a set height on your wrapper, perhaps you should change it to a min-height - especially as your width is 100% - what happens when the screen is not very wide and the wrappers stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated based on a comment

You could do that using [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

```css
.div-c {
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 display: flex;              /* added property */
 align-items: center;        /* added property, will center its children vertical */
 overflow: hidden            /* added property, will cut of overflowed elements */
}

.div-a-b-wrapper {
 min-width: 100px;           /* changed property, keep them at min. 100px */
 margin: 0 5px;
 border: 1px dotted red;
 /* height: 100%; */         /* removed this or else they always take 100% height */
}

.div-a {
 background-color: red;
}

.div-b {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-c">

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi. This seems like the best solution. But using flexbox causes all the divs to cramp inside div-c doesn't it. Is there a way to use flexbox without having div-a-b-wrapper resize to fit inside div-c? If you are wondering, I'd like to make this sort of a slider where excessive div-a-b-wrapper which are cut off are accessed with a next / previous button.

Comment: @user3607282 When you say _the div's cramp_, do you mean the blue area collapsed to its content? ... If, as you can see I removed the `height: 100%` from the div-a-b-wrapper, as when there, they will always take full height of div-c, so I ask: When you meant vertical centered, did you mean the div-a-b-wrappers or the div-a/div-b ?

Comment: I meant stop this happening - https://jsfiddle.net/c58wL92d/ . Can we let the div-a-b-wrapper (the red and blue divs together) overflow from parent div-c so that the excessive div-a-b-wrapper are cutoff?

Comment: what I mean is - how can I keep the div-a-b-wrapper at 100px even when more div-a-b-wrappers are added into div-c

Comment: "did you mean the div-a-b-wrappers or the div-a/div-b ?" - div-a-b-wrapper should be the one that's vertically centered. Your solution is correct. Just that part about width changing when I use flexbox is what I need to sort out.

Comment: @user3607282 Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/c58wL92d/2/ ... where I added `overflow: hidden;` to div-c and changed to `min-width: 100px;` on div-a-b-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
.div-c {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.div-a-b-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
   width: 100px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   border: 1px dotted red;
}

.div-a {
   background-color: red;
   width: 100%;
}

.div-b {
   background-color: blue;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.div-c {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 padding:20px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.div-a-b-wrapper {
 width: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 height: 100%;
 border: 1px dotted red;
}

.div-a {
 background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
}

.div-b {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
Try this:

<div class="div-c">
     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution to look into. Highly recommend flexbox.

```css
.div-c {
width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #333; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around;
}

.div-a-b-wrapper {
 width: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 height: 100%;
 border: 1px dotted red;
}

.div-a {
 background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
}

.div-b {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-c">
     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flex-box

Apply the following styles to   `div-c`

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Then apply

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

to `div-a-b-wrapper`

```css
.div-c {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.div-a-b-wrapper {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
}

.div-a {
  background-color: red;
}

.div-b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-c">
  <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
    <div class="div-a">a</div>
    <div class="div-b">b</div>
  </div>

  <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
    <div class="div-a">a</div>
    <div class="div-b">b</div>
  </div>

  <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
    <div class="div-a">a</div>
    <div class="div-b">b</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 different panels inside a container.
You can use the following code:

```
#content{
    float: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 60%;
}
#navbar{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 20%;
    display:block;
    margin-right: 80%;
}
#rightpanel{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: justify;
    display: block;
}
#container{
    position: absolute;
    float:none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

After including this in the project, you can use the following code syntax to vertically align the content div in the center:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class = "navbar">
      left column content goes here.....
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      content goes here....
   </div>
   <div class="rightpanel">
      right panel...
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may be this will help you.

```css
.div-c {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.div-a-b-wrapper {
 width: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;

 border: 1px dotted red;
}

.div-a {
 background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
}

.div-b {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-c">
     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/k2e8dzmo/

```
<div class="div-c">
     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

     <div class="div-a-b-wrapper">
      <div class="div-a">a</div>
      <div class="div-b">a</div>
     </div>

    </div>
```

css

```
.div-c {
 width: 100%;
 height: 125px;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
}

.div-a-b-wrapper {
 width: 100px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;


}

.div-a {
 background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
}

.div-b {
  margin-top:5px;
 background-color: blue;
 width: 100%;
 height:75px;
}
```

Comment: Rather than throw code at the wall, with the comment "try this," provide an explanation of what your posted code does, how it achieves the end-result. Detail any caveats, of which you're aware, compatibility problems....

Answer (score -2):

Maybe put a center inside div-c like:

```
<div-c>
 <center>
  <divs></div>
 </center>
</div-c>
```

Comment: the center tag is deprecated and shouldn't be used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: Except the `<center>` element was deprecated, if not obsoleted, a long, *long* time ago. Also it centers along the horizontal axis, not the vertical, so it also doesn't achieve the desired end-result.